# Difference between {`${props.title} `} and {props.title}

Tags: javascript, reactjs, template-strings

I see in some places, to get the value of title from props, we use

```
{`${props.title} `}
```

while in some other places, we use it

```
{props.title}
```

What is the difference?

Comment: There's a space in it, so it would need to be `{ props.title+" " }`. If it weren't for the space, you could (should?) equivalently write `{ String(props.title) }`

Answer (score 2):

The first option is using template literals, read further [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) from the documentation:

> Template literals are string literals allowing embedded expressions. You can use multi-line strings and string interpolation features with them.

The second option is just passing a string value to the attribute.

Consider the following:

```js
const data = {
  title: 'random title'
};

console.log(data.title);
console.log(`${data.title}`);
```

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

The first one is used when you have to use some string literals. For eg, when you want to append something to your `title` in this case.

If you want to use only `title`, generally, the second one is used.

Answer (score 0):

Both answers already here are good. I don't know the context of your question but in your exemple the difference between

> {`${props.title} `}

and

> {props.title}

is maybe because on the first one using the template literals there is an extra spacing before the last backtick.

It's usefull with jsx when you want to do something like

```
<p>
 {`${props.withExtraSpacing}: some text`}
</p>
```

instead of

```
<p>
 {props.withoutExtraSpacing} + " " + ": some text"
</p>
```